# Can a PC have more than 1 hostname with a single operating system or with 2 operating systems?

Tags: hostname

That's a question that came into my mind because with what I learned, the hostname is something closer to the real world than the logic world, the hostname is a name to identify the machine physically.
But as you can configure the hostname in the operating system, could you have more than 1 hostname if you have in your PC 2 operating systems? Or even with only 1 operating system?
That would be very strange for me because it's like going against what I learnt, but it can make sense thinking about...it's just configuration of the operating system, of course I could have 2 hostnames with 2 operating systems

Comment: A name is just a name. Unless it is stipulated to be unique, anything could have more than one name. At some point of time, I assigned more than 5 hostnames to one of my machines which has a single operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of an object is decided by the person or entity that calls it by that name, not by the object whose name it is. A given person can decide to use more than one name for the same object, and even if they use a single name, different people may use different names. Computers are no exception. A computer can have multiple names, typically because these names used in different contexts.

Under most operating systems, including all Unix variants (Linux, macOS, etc.) and Windows, there is one name that is known as *the hostname*, which is what the `hostname` command displays. You can change the hostname, but at any given point in time, there is only one hostname.

Usually administrators use a single name for a single machine to avoid confusion and to simplify configuration. But that's just a human decision.

Host names mostly matter when a computer is networked: that's how you refer to that computer from other computers. The usual way to declare host names is through [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System). It's possible to configure a computer to obtain its own hostname via [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) based on the computer's [MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address), but it's more common to go the other way round: the computer knows its own hostname, and obtains its connectivity settings through DHCP. Some other services to access computers over a network that may need to be configured separately from DNS are [Active Directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) and [LDAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol). See [How to make a machine accessible from the LAN using its hostname](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16890/how-to-make-a-machine-accessible-from-the-lan-using-its-hostname)
 for a Unix perspective on that topic.

See also [a more Unix-centric answer to a similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50485/what-are-the-ramifications-of-setting-the-hostname/50529#50529).

If you dual boot, you can choose to use different hostnames under different operating systems. As a philosophical question, is it the same computer if it's the same hardware but a completely different software setup? As a practical question, do you want to use the same configuration on both operating systems, in situations where some configuration depends on the host name? The answer depends on how you use the different OSes.